# Move dynamodb tables to different region via global tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

looking to move a handful of tables to a different region and all the instructions are pointing at creating backups and moving them via s3, but i'm trying to be lazy and wondering if I could use global tables instead.

1. enable global tables replication on existing table(s) with replication in the target region
2. change my code to start calling the new region endpoint
3. turn off global tables in the new region by deleting the replication

seems too easy but seems like it would work.  what am i not thinking of?

so far i've created the replication in the new region and can see the delete replication option when i log into the new region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a standard use of global tables. It allows you to avoid any downtime during the move.

You usually want to access the DynamoDB endpoint in the region local to your code and not be doing cross-region calls, so you prob want to think about moving the parts that aren't DynamoDB as well.

In your step 3 you say delete the new region. I assume you mean old region. Yes, you can do this, just note you can't do it during the first 24 hours after setting up the replication.

Comment: awesome thanks.  3 meant to go into the new region and delete the replication in the old region.  :)

interesting that i couldn't find this simply explained anywhere

marking as solved.